# Not able to view Emulator in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am not able to view the android studio emulator in Android studio

1. android studio version: Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 4

I have also enabled `Launch in a tool window`, but I am not able to see the emulator option in `View -> Tool Windows`
How do I fix this?

Comment: Is the emulator installed (check Android SDK)? What OS do you use Linux, Windows, MacOS) and what CPU type?

Comment: Yes, I am using a Pixel 4 XL emulator API level 29, windows 11, intel i7 9th gen, also before the emulator used to open in the tool window

Comment: You should be able to start an emulator via `Tools` menu -> AVD manager -> select virtual device and klick the green Play button in the column "Actions" of the virtual device.

Comment: It still opens as another window